# React won't render more than one component

Tags: reactjs

**Component 1: Does only render if standing alone**

```
const React = require('react');
class URI extends React.Component {render() { return <h1>URI</h1>; }}
module.exports = URI;
```

**Component 2: Renders correctly, but disappears when  is placed before**

```
const React = require('react');

class CONTAINER extends React.Component {render() { return <div style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}} />}}

module.exports = CONTAINER;
```

**App.js:**

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

const URI = require('./uri.jsx');
const CONTAINER = require('./container.jsx');


ReactDOM.render(

  <URI /> // breaks the whole thing but does not when standing alone.
  <CONTAINER> </CONTAINER>

//////Tried
/*
<CONTAINER>   <URI /></CONTAINER>
<URI> </URI>
<CONTAINER/>
*/

,document.getElementById('root'));
```

So I just try to put URI inside container, but what I see in my browser is just the container. First time using react, already more complicated than HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using **React.Fragment**

It allows us to use more than one components in **render** without wrapping them inside an unnecessary parent component/html element always.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <URI />
    <CONTAINER>
    </CONTAINER>
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass only one component as the first parameter in ReactDOM.render();

If you have multiple components, have them all inside one component.

Example: I have added URI and CONTAINER inside div. I am passing div as the 1st parameter.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <URI/>
    <CONTAINER/>
  </div>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: correct, and with React 16, we can also use **<React.Fragment>** as a wrapper instead of **div**
This is one powerful thing which we can utilize, amongst many other React 16 features :) .

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to remember about a React component is that you're writing the *implementation* of an element (like `<img />` or `<span />`).  The browser follows a specification that says "It is invalid for `img` to have children" - so it does the right thing when you pass it `<img>What does this even *mean*?</img>`.

React lets you (as the component / element author) control whether or not you *accept* children, by passing all of the elements your element is "wrapped around" in your `props`, specifically in the `children` field.  So, in your example, with a class-based component `this.props.children`.  If you want `CONTAINER` to be a container, you just need to specify where your children go:

```
const React = require('react');

class CONTAINER extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}

module.exports = CONTAINER;
```

Then you can use it in the way you'd expect to use an HTML element that accepts children:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CONTAINER>
    <URI />
  </CONTAINER>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

You can shorten this with functional components:

```
module.exports = function CONTAINER(props) {
  return <div style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

And even more with a bit of ES2015 sugar:

```
module.exports = ({ children }) =>
  <div style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{children}</div>
```

But whatever style you use, you are in control over where (and whether) you accept child "DOM" nodes as children for your component.